# Hovering a textbox in a Menu/submenu item closes the item in the latest Chrome version

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When the cursor enters a textbox that is inside of a submenu item, the respective submenu is closed. Observable only in the latest version of Google Chrome (55.0.2883.75 m).

Reproduction of the problem:

http://dojo.telerik.com/OvURe

http://dojo.telerik.com/ipihu/3

How can I solve this problem?

([Original Reference](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/2524))

Comment: I can't reproduce this using Chrome Version 55.0.2883.95, on macOS Sierra. What Operating System are you running? Also have you disabled all plugins?

Comment: I can see the error its happening

Comment: OS: windows 10 Pro 64 bits  and Chrome: 55.0.2883.87 m.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this with the following code:

```
function getChromeVersion() {     
        var raw = navigator.userAgent.match(/Chrom(e|ium)\/([0-9]+)\./);
        return raw ? parseInt(raw[2], 10) : false;
}
    function filterNormalInChrome() {
         $(".k-header-column-menu").on("click",function() {
              if (getChromeVersion() >= 55) {  //Chrome version
                 $("ul.k-widget.k-reset.k-header.k-menu.k-menu-vertical").each(function() {
                     $._data($(this).get(0), "events")["pointerout"][0] = 0;
                 });
              }
         });
    }
    $(window).load(function () {
        filterNormalInChrome();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     input{
        pointer-events:none;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#menu").kendoMenu();


          $(document).on("click",".k-link",function(){
                 $(this).find('input').focus();
         });
        });
```

Comment: I am dealing with:
$("ul.k-widget.k-reset.k-header.k-menu.k-menu-vertical").off("pointerout");
$("ul.k-widget.k-reset.k-header.k-menu.k-menu-vertical").on("pointerout", function() {
    /*do stuff*/

});



But I do not know how to keep the style on the menu. The answer you give does not work in grid because it loses the focus.